# AutoNumber Integer to Varchar with min ID

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with column `FirstName`, `Middle_Initial`, `Last_Name`, `Date_of_Birth`,  `MemberID` and `ID` that could have many "flavors" to
Currently the table has an `ID` which is an AutoNumber, Integer.

Example:

```
 FIRST_NAME     MIDDLE_INITIAL     LAST_NAME      DOB          MEMBER_ID     ID
 John                              Doe            01/01/1984   AB123456      1
 John           J                  Doe            01/01/1984   AB123456      2
 John           James              Doe            01/01/1984   AB123456      3
 James                             Smith          12/01/1965   ZY987654      4
 James          K                  Smith          12/01/1965   ZY987654      5
 James                             Smith          08/20/1973   BB754321      6
```

I am looking/hoping to accomplish the following.

Keep all rows; but have the ID update to the minimum ID.

```
 FIRST_NAME     MIDDLE_INITIAL     LAST_NAME      DOB          MEMBER_ID     ID
 John                              Doe            01/01/1984   AB123456      1
 John           J                  Doe            01/01/1984   AB123456      1
 John           James              Doe            01/01/1984   AB123456      1
 James                             Smith          12/01/1965   ZY987654      4
 James          K                  Smith          12/01/1965   ZY987654      4
 James                             Smith          08/20/1973   BB754321      6
```

>
My SQL skills drop off to figure out how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry, had to edit/re-post.  The idea is that the Uniqueness is based off of MEMBER_ID

Comment: Is the ID field a primary key?

Comment: I created my example incorrectly.

Comment: The vague matching of names is adequate for at least a master's degree dissertation. Can you explain what algorithm you have in mind for determining _equality_? Once you have that down, one of the [ranking functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) should be able to handle the rest. You should still keep a unique primary key around, e.g. an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: edited my original post to clarify.  I actually do have a Unique Key being the MemberID

Comment: Did you even try select table.*, MIN(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY memberID) AS "MinID" from table  before accepting the more complex anser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `UPDATE`:

```
;WITH cte AS(SELECT MEMBER_ID,
                    MIN(ID) AS ID,
             FROM TableName
             GROUP BY MEMBER_ID)
UPDATE  t SET ID = cte.ID
FROM TableName t
JOIN cte ON t.MEMBER_ID = cte.MEMBER_ID
```

For `SELECT`:

```
;WITH cte AS(SELECT MEMBER_ID,
                    MIN(ID) AS ID,
             FROM TableName
             GROUP BY MEMBER_ID)
SELECT t.FIRST_NAME,
       t.MIDDLE_INITIAL,
       t.LAST_NAME,
       t.DOB,
       t.MEMBER_ID,
       cte.ID
FROM TableName t
JOIN cte ON t.MEMBER_ID = cte.MEMBER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just using DOB,LASTNAME and LASTNAME to group these users against the ID?

If yes, then you could use

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY DOB,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME ORDER BY DOBDESC) RN FROM YOURTABLE) A
WHERE A.RN = 1
ORDER BY MEMBNO
```

to get the results you need and then assign a new ID for each entry that matches the results in the row using DOB and LASTNAME

Answer (score 0):

```
select table.*, getFirst.firstID
  from table  
  join (select memberID, min(ID) as firstID 
          from table 
         group by memberID ) as getFirst 
    on table.memberID = getFirst.memberID
```

I think this will work also

```
select table.*, MIN(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY memberID) AS "MinID"
  from table
```